# How can I create a thumbnail from an mpg video with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, thumbnails, mpeg

I'd like to process a directory of mpg's in a batch to have a thumbnail using C#/.NET.

Does anyone have any good suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not C# .NET but [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a great tool to do exactly this. Can be run as a command line tool from any language.

[Here's a small tutorial](http://blog.jeffhaynie.us/extract-thumbnail-from-video.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

I did this a few years ago, but I seem to have lost the source. Anyway, the route-of-least-resistance I found was to use DirectShow, there is an interop wrapper for managed code, namely [directshow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html). You'll want to use [IMediaDet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390180(VS.85).aspx)'s [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390182(VS.85).aspx) from the [Windows Media Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407257(VS.85).aspx).

There is an example on CodeProject: [Extract Frames from Video Files](http://69.10.233.10/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the CodeProject site. I'll try to use it in my project.